# stripe payment in vue application by cdn

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments

I'm using vue as CDN because app is really simple.
at this point when I add the code

```
<div id="app">
<!-- some code here -->
    <form action="/charge" method="POST">
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= stripePublishableKey %>"
          data-amount="2500"
          data-name="ec-system payment"
          data-description="You will pay this money for something!"
          data-locale="auto">
    </script>
    </form>
</div>
```

This code gives me the error something like below.

> Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI.
>   Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as
>   , as they will not be parsed

I found some npm library like "vue-stripe" but I don't know how I can use this library when I use vue with cdn not the vue-cli.

Answer (score 0):

In vue, you can not use script tag inside of template.
In your case you could use this library called "vue-stripe-checkout".
This library supports in two ways

> 1. NPM or Yarn
>
> npm install vue-stripe-checkout --save
>
> yarn add vue-stripe-checkout
>
> 2. CDN
>
> https://unpkg.com/vue-stripe-checkout/build/vue-stripe-checkout.js

You can use second method by including cdn into your app.
Please refer this [vue-stripe-checkout](https://github.com/jofftiquez/vue-stripe-checkout) for detailed information.